# MATLAB Count spheres with overlap

Tags: matlab, count

I am trying to count the number of spheres based on intensity value. The spheres are biomarkers from a CT scan. Therefore the center has the largest intensity. However, it is hard for me to count the spheres if there are overlaps. How can we figure out how to do the count of the spheres with overlap.

[image]
[image: eThis is a section of the real image I am using]

Comment: How do the spheres overlap? Are they not solid? Somehow they intersect each other? Or are you looking at a 2D projection of the 3D scan?

Comment: I am looking at a 2D projection of the 3D scan. Thank!

Comment: Then why not count spheres in the 3D scan? There wouldn’t be any overlap there.

Comment: While @CrisLuengo's suggestion is the simplest if you have access to the 3d information (and aren't using these benighted 4d hyperspheres like mine), you might try using a [watershed transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/watershed.html).

Comment: Hi, what could be eaiser if I only have the 2D data instead of 3D? and I see that in watershed transform, it asks to calculate the distance between the two spheres, but in reality, there are multiple overlaps between more than 2 spheres. So I feel like it would be hard to calculate it every time?

Comment: I just added an real image that I am using

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to throw away information. If you've got 3d data, you should use it.

Comment: I understand that. But I was only given the 2D image from the center

Answer (score 0):

for a 3D binary image, you can call `bwlabeln` (https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabeln.html) in the image processing toolbox to count/label isolated islands, but this can be slow.

if you download my iso2mesh toolbox (http://github.com/fangq/iso2mesh), you can also try the `bwislands` function

https://github.com/fangq/iso2mesh/blob/master/bwislands.m

or, create isosurfaces first and then count the closed surface components using `finddisconnsurf` in iso2mesh.

```
fv=isosurface(im, 0.5);
fc=finddisconnsurf(fv.faces);
length(fc)
```

Comment: How is computing an isosurface faster than labeling?

Comment: it is actually possible - `isosurface` calls the marching cube algorithm and only handles the boundary voxels, while `bwlabeln` uses flood-filling algorithm to trace all voxels in the image. it depends on the size of the inclusions, object counts and `bwlabeln` connectivity requirements.

Comment: I doubt anyone still uses a flood-fill algorithm to implement labeling. The algorithms based on Union-Find are essentially O(n), they run through the image once in storage order. To compute an isosurface you need to visit all pixels also, can’t visit only boundary pixels because you don’t know in advance which those are.

Comment: What if I don't have asscess to the 2D Info

Comment: Hi, FangQ and Cris. Wondering if you could help~

Comment: have you looked at my answer above? it works on 3D data directly